# Android Wear debug app gone after reboot

Tags: wear-os

When I develop my Wear App and install (run) it via USB from Android Studio, everything works fine. Even when I disconnect the Watch from USB, it still works, and it remains in the Wear Launcher.

But after rebooting the Watch, my app is gone. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I think it has something to do with installing the debug version after uninstalling the release version. I found the following lines in the log at device start:

```
08-03 17:50:51.908: I/WearablePkgInstaller(617): Sending uninstall intent to PackageInstaller Intent { act=com.google.android.clockwork.packagemanager.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE pkg=com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller (has extras) } for de.eseidinger.myapp
08-03 17:50:52.123: I/WearablePkgInstaller(807): Sent delete request for de.eseidinger.myapp
08-03 17:50:52.237: I/ActivityManager(445): Force stopping de.eseidinger.myapp appid=10029 user=-1: uninstall pkg
08-03 17:50:52.240: I/ActivityManager(445): Force stopping de.eseidinger.myapp appid=10029 user=0: pkg removed
```

These lines tell me that my app was uninstalled at startup but not why. Right before these lines were lines like the following:

```
08-03 17:50:51.902: I/WearablePkgInstaller(617): Fingerprint, force install, and device fingerprint are unchanged for com.google.android.music
```

So maybe it has something to do with my debug version not being signed.

Anyway... What helped was doing a factory reset on my watch AND phone.